# Running a Javascript loop inside a bootstrap "row"

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to pull the 12 latest tumblr posts to a website and maintain the bootstrap structure, but I can't figure out how to make the loop pull different photos for each of the span4's. Right now it is pulling 12 rows, each photo is repeated 3 times, I would like it to be 4 rows of 3 photos where each is different. Can anyone help out here?

```
function formatPhotoHTML(post) {
    var html = '<div class="container">';
    html += '<div class="row">';
    html += '<div class="span4">';

    for (var i = 0; i < post.photos.length; i++) {
        var photo = post.photos[i] ;
        html += '<div class="individualpost" style="background-image:url(' + photo.original_size.url + '); background-position:center center;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover; height:360px; width:100%;"></div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="span4">';
        var photo = post.photos[i];
        html += '<div class="individualpost" style="background-image:url(' + photo.original_size.url + '); background-position:center center;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover; height:360px; width:100%;"></div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="span4">';
        var photo = post.photos[i];
        html += '<div class="individualpost" style="background-image:url(' + photo.original_size.url + '); background-position:center center;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover; height:360px; width:100%;"></div>';
        html += '</div>';
    }

    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';

    return html;
}

function appendPostToPage(post) {
  $('.postspot').append(post);
}

function getPosts() {
    $.getJSON('(TUMBLR_API_KEY)',
    function(r) {
        var posts = r.response.posts;

        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            var html = "";

            if (posts[i].type === "text") {
                html = formatTextHTML(posts[i]);
            } else if (posts[i].type === "photo") {
                html = formatPhotoHTML(posts[i]);
            }

        appendPostToPage(html);
    }
});

}


$(document).ready(function() {
  getPosts();
});
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML structure of the final result you want to achieve?

Comment: You declare the variable 3 times with every loop. Also you assign the variable the same value 3 times.

Comment: @Andre it would just be 4 rows of bootstrap <div class="row"> with 3 <div class="span4">'s inside each, so a total of 12 photos in a grid

Comment: @HanletEscaño yea, i don't know how you would declare the variable just once and loop it if you want to have three <div class="span4">'s within each row

Comment: @HanletEscaño I also tried making the second variables [i + 1] and [i + 2] but it didnt work

Comment: @GradyWoodruff if you don't have the loop, you can just access it directly with post.photos[0], post.photos[1] and post.photos[2]

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing 12 rows and each photo repeated 3 times because you are telling function to do so. so in order to show 4 rows and each photo once, remove repeated code inside your function .

```
function formatPhotoHTML(post) {
var closeDivNow =3;
var html = '<div class="container">';
    for (var i = 0; i <=post.photos.length; i++) {
    if(i%3 == 0 || i==0 ){
               html += '<div class="row">';
        }
        var photo = post.photos[i] ;
            html += '<div class="span4">';
            html += '<div class="individualpost" style="background-image:url(' + photo.original_size.url + '); background-position:center center;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover; height:360px; width:100%;"></div>';
            html += '</div>';

        if(i%3 == 0 || i==0 && i == closeDivNow){
                  closeDivNow = closeDivNow + i;
                  html += '</div>';
            }
    }
    html += '</div>';
return html;
}
```

Comment: This will set 1 row with 12 photos inside. OP wants 4 rows with 3 photos each.

Comment: my only question with that is, how do i close the <div class="row"> after every 3rd picture and create a new div class="row"> so that they are in the bootstrap grid?

Comment: @GradyWoodruff you can use the % operator to check if i is divisible by 3.

Comment: You could also fix the width of the container and let bootstrap do its fluid magic.

Comment: @GradyWoodruff like Hanlet Escaño said divide by 3 and check if remainder is 0. I have updated the example. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Ronnie7777 hmm, doesn't seem to be pulling anything, trying to figure out why

Comment: With your updated answer, happens the same as @RollYourOwnEd's, this will open and close the div.row in the same iteration of the loop, i.e., `<div class="row">[0]</div>[1][2]`

Comment: @gradyWoodruff I tested it works for me    for (var i = 0; i <=11; i++) {
            if(i%3 == 0 || i==0 ){
                 alert(i);
            }
        }

Comment: @Andre you are right I forgot to remove extra 'row' div outside the loop

Comment: @Ronnie7777, the extra row was not the problem. The code closes the row on the same item it opens it, so it forms `<div class="row">[0]</div>[1][2]` etc. The row should open before the first and close after the third, e.g. `<div class="row">[0][1][2]</div>`

Comment: @Andre OH!! true. I got you. I will fix it

Comment: @GradyWoodruff it's fixed now. give one more shot

Answer (score 2):

This will add the `div.row"` every time three photos.

No cleverness to avoid a inner loop, this code is easier to understand:

```
function formatPhotoHTML(post) {
    var html = '<div class="container">';

    var photos_per_row = 3;
    for(var row = 0; row < post.photos.length; row += photos_per_row)
    {
        html += '<div class="row">'; // open div.row
        for(var i = row; i < (row + photos_per_row); i++)
        {
            var photo = post.photos[i];
            html += '<div class="span4">'; // open span4
            html += '<div class="individualpost" style="background-image:url(' + photo.original_size.url + '); background-position:center center;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover; height:360px; width:100%;"></div>';
            html += '</div>'; // close span4
        }
        html += '</div>'; // close div.row
    }

    html += '</div>'; // close div.container
    return html;
}
```

I made a fiddle. [You can check it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/hwmtvsf0/)

Answer (score 0):

OK so you're pulling 12 posts here:

```
function getPosts() {
    $.getJSON('(TUMBLR_API_KEY)',
    function(r) {
        var posts = r.response.posts;

        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            var html = "";

            if (posts[i].type === "text") {
                html = formatTextHTML(posts[i]);
            } else if (posts[i].type === "photo") {
                html = formatPhotoHTML(posts[i]);
            }

        appendPostToPage(html);
    }
});

}
```

You could use the modulas operator to work out every time you've looped through three posts like so instead:

```
var html = '<div class="container">';

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

        if( (i%3 == 0 ){

           html += '<div class="row">'; // opening row every 3
        } 

        html += '<div class="span4">';
        html += '<div class="individualpost" style="background-image:url(' + photo.original_size.url + '); background-position:center center;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover; height:360px; width:100%;"></div>';
        html += '</div>';

        if( i%3 == 2 ){

           html += '</div>'; // closing row every 3
        } 



}

html += '</div>'; //closing container
```

Mine's a bit rough but that should work...

Comment: This will open and close the `div.row` in the same iteration of the loop, i.e., `<div class="row">[0]</div>[1][2]`